# Why JDK includes JRE?

Tags: java

I need to clear some thing regarding JDK aan JRE which are available from Oracle and please 
correct me if I am wrong.

We can run our java programs with JRE and It does not need JDK.
But for the development of Program we need JDK, Which come with JRE.

1. Does JRE is needed for the development of programs? If no then why JDK includes JRE?
2. Is JDK is available with out JRE for development?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541319/jre-included-with-jdk-vs-standalone-jre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK is just a bundle and of course you need the runtime environment JRE to run your own software you just developed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would be a bit silly shipping a java compiler without being able to run the resulting programs...

It also makes sure you use the same version of java to run your app as you did to compile it (the class file version changed between 1.6 and 1.7, meaning old versions can't read 1.7 class files).