# What features would I go to miss if JDK is not installed?

Tags: java

I would like to know if JRE is installed in my computer but not JDK, then what features am I going to miss?

I have faced this interview question recently. I am seeking for it, but could not found answer searching in Google and some other places.

Thanks Sir.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where I did make wrong?

Comment: This isn't the right place for that question. StackOverflow is for asking about issues with code. If you needed help with Java code, then this would be the place.

Comment: @CConard96 So, where is the right place to ask this question?

Comment: The JRE *comes* with a JVM - if it did not, compiled Java classes could not be *executed* by the JVM. Did you mean ".. but not JDK"? (The JDK also comes with the tools to *compile* Java source into class files.)

Comment: Everything (except use of disk space). Without a JVM to execute them, your class files are useless piles of bytecode.

Comment: Ok, I actually meant JDK.

Comment: You need to study some basics of Java first. Then research, then come to ask here

Comment: @CConard96 then why did not you flagged it as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

The JRE comprises the JVM and a few tools. You might be mixing this up with the difference between the JRE and the JDK. "JRE" means "Java Runtime Environment", which means the JVM, which means the "Java Virtual Machine". "JDK" means the Java Development Kit, which is everything in the JRE (including the JVM), plus additional tools like the compiler "javac" that allow you to create Java code.

In short, the JRE is what you need to run Java code, including the JVM, and the JDK is what you need to write Java code.

This is covered in the documentation for Java, which I recommend that you read.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE is used for execute java aplications (when the software exists). JDK is used for software developers (for create a new software).

Comment: I am not seeking for definition. I am seeking for provided feature difference by the tool.

Comment: There are no new features between JDK and JRE because both are used for different things. If you are using any tool like an IDE you need JDK inclusive if the IDE don't tell it to you. JDK have libraries for developers inclusive the documentation for every library.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the answer about having only JRE in [JRE included with JDK vs. standalone JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541319/jre-included-with-jdk-vs-standalone-jre.In) this link,you will see that If you installed only JRE,then you will lack the tools included with the JDK (JavaDB, javac, tools.jar, etc).